# How to use Path (android.graphics.Path) with canvas in android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am working on a Custom View that implements Catch application like Circular Menu. After spending a lot of time, I have made a bit of progress, completed outer semi-circle with multile colors. Now, reading an answer provided by developer of Catch application to an user for his query, I came across the class Path. Google Android Developer page does not provides enough material to be understood and to be familiar with Path. so, Please ? Anyone ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use it to draw lines on a canvas. A path is basically a collection of lines. You can use it to create shapes that are not standard. E.g. there a lots of functions to create some default shapes:

```
canvas.drawRect();
canvas.drawArc(RectF oval, float startAngle, float sweepAngle, boolean useCenter, Paint paint);
canvas.drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint);
canvas.drawLine(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Paint paint);
canvas.drawOval(RectF oval, Paint paint);
canvas.drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint);
```

But if you want something custom, you can create a path, and by calling

```
// Set the beginning of the next contour to the point (x,y).
void     moveTo(float x, float y)

// Add a line from the last point to the specified point (x,y).
void     lineTo(float x, float y)
```

You have control of the pencil that draws the lines of your path.
[Here's a nice tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2011/08/drawpath-on-canvas.html)

Comment: From the documentation: Add a closed circle contour to the path. For example to draw the point above the 'I'.

Comment: i want to draw that pathData to canvas , if a single vector have multiple pathData i want to draw each pathData to canvas one by one because i want to allow drag/fly each pathdata when i click . How to do that can you please help me?