# Custom shape Recycler View with button Onclick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

[image: Recyclerview Item..star shape with Image[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9hSy.jpg)

I want to view a a stagged recycler View  in start shape with profile pic ...When the user clicks on the pic..the image should change to the next image ..and when the red colr..it should open redActivity...Yellow means YellowActivity....etc

How to achieve this...Please don't block r tell me to add some code..As I'm a totally new to android...

Comment: implement on touchlistener and write your own logic of touch coordinates in callback of onTouch method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: how to get the custom shape button or custom shape image @JaydeepPatel

Comment: find library custom shapes like : https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

Comment: on clicking on the red space ,,,,i also need to change the color to white before opening redActivity @JaydeepPatel

Comment: here is some helpful links : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597411/how-to-use-path-android-graphics-path-with-canvas-in-android

Comment: Can you provide some example codes..please...@JaydeepPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an image with any custom shape library;..with relative layout as root....then place the texts inside the layouts as needed and hide and unhide those with in the recycler adapter using an onclick listener